# Virtualización de dispositivos móviles en Android Studio con procesador AMD Ryzen

Tags: android-studio, virtualización, hardware

soy nuevo por acá. La razón por la que entro en este foro es para solicitar su ayuda con un tema. Me estoy enseñando apenas a usar el Android Studio y tengo entendido que la única forma de virtualizar dispositivos en el PC es con un pocesador Intel i5 o superior. Yo cuento con un AMD Ryzen 3 2200g, me preguntaba si no existe alguna forma alternativa para virtualizar los dispositivos con este procesador. Les agradezco mucho las respuestas.

Comment: intenta con genymotion, yo logre virtualizar android en esa apicacion. pero el arranque era tardado. tengo un AMD A8 7410. la verdad no compile ninguna aplicacion creada desde android studio y visualozarlo desde genymotion. tendrias que averiguar como configurarlo con android studio.

Comment: Es buena opción la que sugiere Juan al usar Genymotion. Hugo recuerda que las preguntas deben ser basadas en [ask] para que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, al parecer tu pregunta esta "basada en opiniones", saludos.

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]